# Flutter - Text align justify with no half filled lines

Tags: flutter, justify

I'm building a Quran app where I want all pages to have fully filled lines

I tried to use TextAlign.justify and it kinda helped and got this output from it:
[image]

The problem is that the last line is not filled all the way out like this for example:
[image]

I tried to use TextPainter but it removed the onTapGestureRecognizer.
How can I get such an output without removing the tap capability? I also tried line and letter spacing but didn't work too.

Comment: You want the complete text to adjust itself such that it fills entire page ? Meaning you dont want last line to be left with one word , correct ? You want itself to justify such that last line also should have filled sentence. Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong. I am trying to understand the question.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the behavior I'm looking for @KrishnaAcharya

Comment: Hard luck , documentation says, Stretch lines of text that end with a soft line break to fill the width of
the container.Lines that end with hard line breaks are aligned towards the [start] edge. And actually it is for a good reason as the hard line breaks would look very awkard if it is spread accross the width.